# Importing a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

Trying to import a MySQL database using PHP-Admin. When I try to import the file backed-up by my host, I get this error message:

```
SQL query:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta`

MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected
```

I have also tried to export the database myself, then trying to import that specific file. When I do that, however, I get a completely different error message:

```
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: select a database - `USE mydatabase;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `USE` a database. You could edit your file and add the line at the top, something like:

```
USE databasename;
```

Some tools will let you set a default database when restoring from backup. If you haven't selected one that could be a problem.

If you haven't created a database you'll need to do that first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select which database you are importing to in your SQL. Your first statement should be:

```
USE DATABASE `db_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no database selected.

Find which databases exist

```
SHOW DATABASES:
```

and then select one for use

```
USE `database_name`
```

You say that you are importing into a new host, so I would assume that you do not already have a database created;

```
CREATE DATABASE `database_name`
```

*Now* you can `USE` that database you just created; and your queries should now work.